# Adding headers to framework for release

Tags: xcode, frameworks, header

I'm building a framework project in XCode and everything builds and looks great except there is no `Headers` directory in the built `Foo.framework`.

Do I have to add an explicit build phase for this or is there just a setting to which I'm oblivious? `PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH` looks promising, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mark the public headers as such (frameworks can have private or project headers that are not exposed publicly in the built framework). Select the framework's target in the Targets group (or the "Copy Headers" build phase within the target). In the target's file list (in the "Detail pane"), change the "Role" popup for public headers to "Public".